# relativedelta in python when working in months

Tags: python, relativedelta

Suppose I am working with relative delta when it comes to months.

The problem is when I do:

```
x = relativedelta(months=12)
x.months
> 0
```

This is a problem when I try to do something like this:

```
y = relativedelta(months=12) - relativedelta(months=4)

y
> relativedelta(years=+1, months=-4)

y.months
> -4
```

I was hoping for a months value of 8 (12 - 4). Anyone know how to best approach this so I can achieve the output I am looking for?

Comment: `relativedelta(months=12)` is actually `relativedelta(years=+1)` It automatically converts months to years. For example `months=13` would results in `relativedelta(years=+1, months=+1)`

Answer (score 4):

`relativedelta(months=12)` is actually `relativedelta(years=+1)` It automatically converts months to years. For example `months=13` would result in `relativedelta(years=+1, months=+1)`

Further, years only change when months go below -11 or above 11. So if the amount of  `months` after the operation is still between -11 and 11, the year will not change.

The solution would be that you need to look at both the `rdelta.years` and `rdelta.months` values to get the "net months" you're looking for.

```
def total_months(rdelta):
    return (rdelta.years * 12) + rdelta.months
```

You could subclass `relativedelta` to make this a bit more intuitive for your use.

```
class reldelta(relativedelta):
    @property
    def total_months(self):
        return (self.years * 12) + self.months
```

Then

```
>>> delta = reldelta(years=1) - relativedelta(months=4)
>>> delta
reldelta(years=+1, months=-4)
>>> delta.total_months
8
```

Of course, this can get messy if you want to try to factor in days to this, because the number of days in a month changes. This is why `days` are not bounded like months are

```
>>> relativedelta(days=9999)
relativedelta(days=+9999)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
y = (relativedelta(months=12) - relativedelta(months=4)).months % 12
```

Essentially, I have used modulo to mitigate the out of bounds values (<0 and >12).